# How do I remove a member from an Exchange Distribution List?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2007

How do you remove users from Exchange Distribution Lists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### GUI

1. `Microsoft Exchange > Microsoft Exchange On-Premises > Receipient Configuration > Distribution Group`
2. Right-Click on Distribution Group and "Properties"
3. Go to Members tab
4. Right-Click user and choose "Remove"

[image: Is it that hard to type your request into Google?]

## Management Shell (Powershell)

```
Remove-DistributionGroupMember -identity "Group Name" -Member "Group Member"
```